# Is it possible to draw direction arrows using SLD of GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I have one record in MySQL with LINESTRING field which contains list of points.

Is it possible to draw direction arrows over whole line using SLD of GeoServer? Or i need split my one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<TextSymbolizer>
    <Label>
        <ogc:Literal>&#xE112;</ogc:Literal>
        <!-- "arrow" symbol -->

    </Label>
    <Font>
        <CssParameter name="font-family">Lucida Sans</CssParameter>
        <CssParameter name="font-size">12</CssParameter>
    </Font>
    <LabelPlacement>
        <LinePlacement>
            <PerpendicularOffset>-1</PerpendicularOffset>
            <!-- position of "arrow" -->
        </LinePlacement>
    </LabelPlacement>
    <Fill>
        <CssParameter name="fill">#00FF00</CssParameter>
    </Fill>
    <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
    <!-- used with LabelPlacement/LinePlacement -->
    <VendorOption name="forceLeftToRight">false</VendorOption>
    <!-- to follow direction of points -->
    <VendorOption name="repeat">100</VendorOption>
    <!-- to place several "arrows" over whole line -->
</TextSymbolizer>
```

[GeoServer labeling](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. I was looking for the same thing few months ago - [here's what i found](http://blog.geoserver.org/2009/04/02/follow-the-arrows/).

It's working - [I've tried](http://mapa.abakus.net.pl/mapa.html#zoom=12&lat=217528.23826&lon=502908.39937&layers=B0TTTT)